# Swift C callback - takeUnretainedValue or takeRetainedValue for Swift class pointer

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have several `UIView` or `UITableViewCell`. Inside I have C callback, for example:

```
CCallback(bridge(self),
       {(observer, data) -> Void in
          let mySelf = Unmanaged<DetailedView>.fromOpaque(observer!).takeRetainedValue()
           mySelf.fillLoadedData(data: data)
        });
```

Somewhere else

```
func bridge<T : AnyObject>(_ obj : T) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
}
```

In C:

```
void CCalback(void * classPtr, void(*callback)(void *, MyData)){
   //fill data
   callback(classPtr, data)
}
```

Should I use `takeUnretainedValue` or `takeRetainedValue` in closure? As far as I understand this, retained will increase objects reference count, so it wont be auto-destructed? Otherwise, if I use `takeUnretainedValue`, if self is auto-released, this will crash, so using `takeRetainedValue` will prevent it. Am I correct?

Comment: What is `bridge(self)` ?

Comment: @MartinR Code added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object pointer can be converted to a `Unsafe(Mutable)RawPointer` (the Swift
equivalent of the C `void *`) with or without retaining the object:

```
let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
// Does not retain `obj`

let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())
// Retains `obj`
```

The conversion back to an object pointer (often done in a callback
function called from C) can be with or without consuming a retain:

```
let obj = Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
// Does not consume a retain

let obj = Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeRetainedValue()
// Consumes a retain
```

If the lifetime of `obj` is *guaranteed* while the callback is active
then the easiest way is to use the "unretained" conversions in both directions. You are responsible for retaining `obj` while the
callback is active, e.g. by unregistering the callback before `obj`
is deinitialized.

The alternative is to use `passRetained()` to convert `obj` to 
a pointer. This retains the object and therefore keeps it "alive".
The callback can still use the "unretained" conversion to convert
the pointer to an object pointer, without decreasing the retain count.
But there must be exactly one `takeRetainedValue()` call to consume the
retain. After that, the object can be destroyed if there are no
other references to it.

More generally, each call to `passRetained(obj)` increases the retain
count and each call to `takeRetainedValue()` decreases it, so they must be properly balanced.